# Comparing strings passed from arguments

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

Creating a node.js addon with C++. I want to check if the passed parameter is `hi`.

The node app:

```
addon.Hello("hi");
```

The C++:

```
if (args[0]->ToString() != "hi") {
  ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::New("Sunday morning rain is falling...")));
  return scope.Close(Undefined());
}
```

But it keeps giving me the errors:

> ../xxx.cc: In static member function ‘static v8::Handle
>   xxx::New(const v8::Arguments&)’: 
>   ../xxx.cc:41:29: error: no
>   match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are ‘v8::Local’ and
>   ‘const char [6]’)
>        if (args[0]->ToString() != "hi") {
>                                ^

Answer (score 0):

`ToString()` returns a String object. You can get a C string from that with something like `char* foo = *String::Utf8Value(args[0]->ToString());`.

Comment: I'm getting an warning with this: `warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour [-Waddress]`. And now what ever I pass as an argument the statement always gets executed.

Comment: This looks like it will create a dangling pointer (although I haven't used V8). You probably have to do `v8::String::Utf8Value s(args[0]->ToString());` and then do `if (0 == std::strcmp(*s, "hi"))`.

Comment: @majidarif You have to use the C string comparison functions like @Simple mentioned. It's not a C++ string. If you really want that instead, do: `string foo = string(*String::Utf8Value(args[0]->ToString()));`

Comment: @mscdex do you mean "0-terminated" by "c string"? I think it's actually just byte array

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I had this same problem, this seems to compile:

```
  using namespace std;

  v8::String::Utf8Value arg2(args[2]->ToString());

  if (strcmp(*arg2, "true") != 0 && strcmp(*arg2, "false") != 0) {
        Nan::ThrowTypeError("Third argument to 'replace-line' must be a string representing whether to find or replace.");
        return;
   }

   bool isReplace = strcmp(*arg2, "false") == 0 ? false : true;
```

I basically arrived at my solution via the comments from the other answer, someone needed to just update a new answer with the actual solution which is what I have done here (I hope).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <node.h>

String::Utf8Value tmp(args[0]->ToString());
arg0 = std::string(*tmp);
//then you can compare string using "== or > or <"
if(arg0 == "hi")
{
    ...
}
```